# GPu Usage on RTX 2080 TI 20% CPU 10% during Render Optix

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm really new to Blender. 
I have a workstation with a Intel i9 9900X and a RTX 2080 Ti and 64 GB of RAM.

I'm rendering a animation in Cycles(Optix - Denoising AI). The strange thing is that the usage of CPU is at 14 % and GPU is at 7-20%. Is there something wrong with my settings or is it the animation?

[image: Settings]

Answer (score 4):

Windows Task Manager does not report GPU usage very well (known problem). If you switch one of the graphs to CUDA, you'll notice it will report full usage for that graph. Third-party GPU monitoring software such as GPU-Z will correctly report GPU usage.

[image]