# Cycles Render CUDA cores usage 0 to 100% spikes slow down render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

I spend a huge amount of time rendering and if this is fixable, I would love it. My machine has dual RTX 2070 supers. In the task manager, on the GPU pages, when I set it to show CUDA usage, the behavior is a bit odd. Sometimes it will show CUDA at 100% or near 100%. In these times it renders each square quickly. However, sometimes I get spikes - where much of the time it shows 0% and then will spike to 100%. When it does this it renders slowly (same scene and it just changes throughout the render).

[image]

First part rendering slowly, second speeding up.

[image]

Beginning and end rendering very quickly, middle slowly.

[image]

Good speed throughout.

[image]

This is the image I was rendering during the above screen captures. It is a large image - over 5000 pixels wide at 1500 samples.

The speed of each square rendering is directly correspondent to the CUDA usage, so I am curious what is the relationship here? Why does it sit at 0% so much? Can I get it to run at 100% constantly? I use Optix to render, not regular CUDA in the blender settings. I am using Blender E-cycles 2.90.1 because I have stability issues with later versions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167254/gpu-usage-on-rtx-2080-ti-20-cpu-10-during-render-optix

Comment: Thanks Allen. That link shows the issue with the task manager not showing CUDA usage - you have to change it from its default (3d) to CUDA. I have it set at CUDA - as can be seen in the screen shots in the original question. So that's not the cause.

Comment: It's my understanding that RT cores and CUDA cores are different, so we may have a similar problem when using OptiX.  I have no way to test this.  I would take the advice of using a different hardware monitor, however.  Look at temp and total power draw for indications whether the card is indeed going idle.